# Is it a good practice to use the collection interface name as part of the variable name?

Tags: java

I know that the use of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is considerate as a bad practice.

But, when we work with collections, the use of the collection interface name  as part of the variable name is a bad practice?

- Example 1:

  ```
   List<Student> listStudents; 
   //or
   List<Student> studentsList;
  ```

  Versus

  ```
   List<Student> students;
  ```
- Example 2:

  ```
  Map<Integer, Student> mapStudents; 
  //or 
  Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap;
  ```

  Versus

  ```
  Map<Integer, Student> students;
  ```
- Example 3:

  ```
     Set<Student> setStudents;  
     //or
     Set<Student> studentsSet
  ```

  Versus

  ```
     Set<Student> students;
  ```

Comment: This is entirely opinion-based, and thus off-topic for SO.

Comment: Indeed, very opinion based, but you are fogetting the option `studentList`, `studentSet`, `studentMap`. Anyway, as an opinion, generally answer is "no", unless you can state why exactly you need to add the type of collection to the name. If you can't give a specific reason, then the default should be to use `students`.

Comment: See [tag:hungarian-notation].

Comment: ...obviously, if you have *both* a set and a map in the same/nested scope, then you need to have different names, so might add `...Set` and `...Map` to names.

Comment: My opinion is that you should avoid adding anything to a variable name that is unrelated to its purpose in the system. Particularly if the actual type of the collection is an internal implementation detail that you want to keep encapsulated. But if your name is otherwise good (see @OldCurmudgeon's answer), appending an unnecessary `...List` or `...Map` to the name is not the end of the world. I'd concentrate on getting the basic name right, as that can genuinely make a massive difference in readability.

Comment: I'd love to see how "hungarian notation"-ing wildcarded collections could turn to dadaism... the beauty of `somethingExtendingStudentSkipListSet` comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose the names more carefully you will often find it much easier if you properly describe what the collection **does** rather than what it **is**.

- Example 1:

  ```
   List<Student> listStudents; **NO**
  ```

  Versus

  ```
   List<Student> allStudents; **YES**
  ```
- Example 2:

  ```
  Map<Integer, Student> studentsByID; **YES**
  ```

  Versus

  ```
  Map<Integer, Student> students; **NO**
  ```
- Example 3:

  ```
     Set<Student> specialNeedsStudents;  **YES**
  ```

  Versus

  ```
     Set<Student> students; **NO**
  ```

Answer (score -2):

I would say that adding the name of the collection to the variable name is usually considered as a bad practice.

There are plenty of tools, which tells you the type of the variable without having to look for definition, which makes this information redundant.